# The connection to service named com.example.myframework.myservice was invalidated

Tags: osx-yosemite

I am developing a custom framework.Inside framework I am using one xpc service for some particular task. When I test this framework using some test application I am getting above error. Could you plz help me out.I believe I missed some configuration for framework, but could not figured out whats that. Did not find any good docs for using xpc in framework.
Thanks!